# Evaluate a limit in terms of derivative

Tags: calculus, limits

If $f$ is differentiable at $x = a$, with $a > 0$, evaluate the following limit in terms of $f'(a)$

$$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}}$$

Comment: Hint: multiply by $$\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}$$

Comment: @Bungo Nice alternative!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Use that

$$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}}=\lim_{x \to a}\left(\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}\cdot \frac{x-a}{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}}\right)$$

Answer (score -1):

Take the derivative (l’hopital rule) to get: ( since it is zero divided by zero)

$f’(x)(2)x^{0.5}$

This gives

$f’(a)(2)a^{0.5}$